# Rename folder in a loop using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a script which will get all mt .avi files in a specific directory, rename the directory after each file and will call another script in a loop:
(the name of the directory is the input)

```
cd /D %1
dir *.avi > avi.list
set x=%1
set z=%1
cd ..
    FOR /F "tokens=1-5" %G IN (avi.list) DO (
    @set y=%K
    rename %x% %y%
    set x=%y%
    C:\indexer\Indexer.exe %y%
    )
rename %y% %z%
cd /D %z%
del avi.list
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Wait so how do you want the batch file to rename directories with multiple .avi files. Please give a good example of what you want the batch file to do.

Comment: I have a directory name 1
and in it many files named "a" "b" "c"...
I want to rename the root folder after the file names in a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both %G and %K need to be %%G and %%K inside a batch file.

You will also need double quoting if the filenames contain spaces or other awkward characters.

There are better methods to get the filename and path **(added filename alone)**: try this

```
@echo off
cd /d "%~1"
   for /f "delims=" %%a in (' dir *.avi /b /a-d ') do (
      echo filename without extension is "%%~na"
      echo name is "%%~nxa"
      echo filepath is "%%~dpa"
      pause
   )
```

At a cmd prompt read the help from: **FOR /?** and on the last page is the list of modifiers.

Comment: can I use in the loop:
"set filename=%%~nxa"

Comment: and also: how can I grab the file name without its extantion?
Thanks!!

Comment: I added the filename alone.  You can set a variable to the terms, but you can also use the terms within the loop, without needing a variable or delayed expansion.  To rename the AVI to just the filename you can use `ren "%%~nxa" "%%~na"` and then use the command `"C:\indexer\Indexer.exe" "%%~na"` if that is what you need to do.